# ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class Date

Tags: r, class, date, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to code a shiny app, and fairly new to R codin. I am reading in .txt files containing 3 columns. One column is a date, two others are numeric(the date column is read as a class character. The text files are selected by the name a user selects. The server than plots the date on the x-axis and the numeric value on the y-axis. I also added a zoom function. 
The app works fine when the date column is not declared (so when the line is deleted, dates are plotted as character). When the column Date is declared as a date by the following code:

```
 inlees$Date <- dmy(inlees$Date) #convert from character to Date
```

the app returns the error:

> Error in : ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class Date

[Snapshot of the text file can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDZP6.jpg)
Any help is appreciated.

I am using the following script:

UI

```
    ui <- fluidPage(selectInput(inputId = "name", label = "Selecteer    analyse", choices=c("TESTOSTERON", 
                        "ANDROSTEENDION", "17OHProgesteron", "P4")),

            plotOutput("p1", dblclick = "p1_dblclick",
                brush = brushOpts(id = "p1_brush", resetOnNew = TRUE)),

            plotOutput("p2", dblclick = "p2_dblclick",
                       brush = brushOpts(id = "p2_brush", resetOnNew = TRUE)))
```

Server

```
    server <- function(input, output) {

    rangesp1 <- reactiveValues(y = NULL)

    selectData <-  reactive ({

    data_path <- "ANPR"   # path to the data
    inlees <- input$name
    files <- dir(data_path, pattern = paste0(inlees,".*\\.txt")) # get file names

  inlees <- files %>%
  # read in all the files, appending the path before the filename
  map(~ read_tsv(file.path(data_path, .), skip = 6, col_names = TRUE))%>% 
  reduce(rbind)

inlees$Date <- dmy(inlees$Date) #convert from character to Date
})

output$p1 <- renderPlot({

p1 <- ggplot(data = selectData(), aes(x = Date, y = Ratio)) + geom_point(color = "#1874CD80") +
  ylab(expression("D0 Ratio")) + theme_bw() + xlab("Date") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12),axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
coord_cartesian(ylim = rangesp1$y)
      p1 })

observeEvent(input$p1_dblclick, {
brush <- input$p1_brush
if (!is.null(brush)) {

  rangesp1$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax)

} else {

  rangesp1$y <- NULL
}
})

rangesp2 <- reactiveValues(y = NULL)
output$p2 <- renderPlot({


p2 <- ggplot(data = selectData(), aes(x = Date, y = ISArea)) + geom_point(color = "#68228B80") +
  ylab(expression("IS Area")) + theme_bw() + xlab("Date") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12),axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = rangesp2$y)
  p2
  })


  observeEvent(input$p2_dblclick, {
  brush <- input$p2_brush
  if (!is.null(brush)) {

    rangesp2$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax)

  } else {    
    rangesp2$y <- NULL
  }
    })

 }

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You are using function `dmy` which constructs objects of class Date from a non-standard package. The function in base package is `as.Date`:  `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C"); as.Date("23-Nov-16", "%d-%b-%y")`

Comment: Thank you, but even when I use library(lubridate), it still does not work

Comment: Welcome to SO. A better post would not mention shiny, and only contain a sample dataset + a minimal ggplot expression reproducing unexpected behaviour

Comment: The error you get is one that can show up when you try to give a vector to the `data` argument of `ggplot`.  Does your reactive function `selectData` return a data.frame?  My guess is that is returning a `Date` vector rather than a data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of explicit `return` statements and this is probably a good example of why using `return()` is a good habit.

The help page of `?function` says:

> If the end of a function is reached without calling return, the value of the last evaluated expression is returned.

Now, the last statement in the reactive expression which defines the `selectData` function is:

```
inlees$Date <- dmy(inlees$Date)
```

So, the last evaluated expression which is of class `Date` - not of class `data.frame` - is returned, subsequently causing the error in `ggplot()`.

Please add `return(inlees)` as last statement in your `reactive()` expression:

```
selectData <-  reactive ({

  data_path <- "ANPR"   # path to the data
  inlees <- input$name
  files <- dir(data_path, pattern = paste0(inlees,".*\\.txt")) # get file names

  inlees <- files %>%
    # read in all the files, appending the path before the filename
    map(~ read_tsv(file.path(data_path, .), skip = 6, col_names = TRUE))%>% 
    reduce(rbind)

  inlees$Date <- dmy(inlees$Date) #convert from character to Date
  return(inlees)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses. Really appreciated. Learned a lot from my first question. I tried your solution Uwe, but then I got in trouble with the error that "ggplot2 does not know how to deal with a list". After you suggestion, I thought, I can also declare the column Date, as a date inside the "read_tsv line and now everything works:):

```
 inlees <- files %>%
  # read in all the files, appending the path before the filename
  map(~ read_tsv(file.path(data_path, .), skip = 6, col_names = TRUE, 
  col_types = cols(Date = col_date(format = "%d-%b-%y")))) %>% 
  reduce(rbind)
```